# Python parsing json file to access values returning TypeError

Tags: python, json, typeerror

I am using python to parse a json file full of url data to try and build a url reputation classifier. There are around 2,000 entries in the json file and not all of them have all of the fields present. A typical entry looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "host_len" : 12,
      "fragment" : null,
      "url_len" : 84,
      "default_port" : 80,
      "domain_age_days" : "5621",
      "tld" : "com",
      "num_domain_tokens" : 3,
      "ips" : [
         {
            "geo" : "CN",
            "ip" : "115.236.98.124",
            "type" : "A"
         }
      ],
      "malicious_url" : 0,
      "url" : "http://www.oppo.com/?utm_source=WeiBo&amp;utm_medium=OPPO&amp;utm_campaign=DailyFlow",
      "alexa_rank" : "25523",
      "query" : "utm_source=WeiBo&amp;utm_medium=OPPO&amp;utm_campaign=DailyFlow",
      "file_extension" : null,
      "registered_domain" : "oppo.com",
      "scheme" : "http",
      "path" : "/",
      "path_len" : 1,
      "port" : 80,
      "host" : "www.oppo.com",
      "domain_tokens" : [
         "www",
         "oppo",
         "com"
      ],
      "mxhosts" : [
         {
            "mxhost" : "mail1.oppo.com",
            "ips" : [
               {
                  "geo" : "CN",
                  "ip" : "121.12.164.123",
                  "type" : "A"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "path_tokens" : [
         ""
      ],
      "num_path_tokens" : 1
   }
]
```

I am trying to access the data stored in the fields "ips" and "mxhosts" to compare the "geo" location. To try and access the first "ips" field I'm using:

```
corpus = open(file)
urldata = json.load(corpus, encoding="latin1")

for record in urldata:
        print record["ips"][0]["geo"]
```

But as I mentioned not all of the json entries have all of the fields. "ips" is always present but sometimes it's "null" and the same goes for "geo". I'm trying to check for the data before accessing it using:

```
if(record["ips"] is not None and record["ips"][0]["geo"] is not None):
```

But I this an error:

```
if(record["ips"] is not None and record["ips"][0]["geo"] is not None):
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I try to check it using this:

```
if("ips" in record):
```

I get this error message:

```
print record["ips"][0]["geo"]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

So I'm not sure how to check if the record I'm trying to access exists before I access it, or if I'm even accessing in the most correct way. Thanks.

Comment: from what I understood above data is the urldata. If that is the case instead of record["ips"][0]["geo"] do record["ips"]["geo"]. this should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Doing that gives me the error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being a little convoluted due to the inconsistent nature of the json file, but I had to end up first checking that "ips" was not null and then checking that "geo" was present in record["ips"][0]. This is what it looks like:

```
if(record["ips"] is not None and "geo" in record["ips"][0]):
                print record["ips"][0]["geo"]
```

Thanks for the feedback everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if `record["ips"]` is not `None`, or more simply if it's `True`, before proceeding to access it as a list; otherwise you would be calling a list method on a `None` object.

```
for record in urldata:
    if record["ips"]:
        print record["ips"][0]["geo"]
```

Comment: You're correct that doing that lets me access the data. Now it prints out a lot of the data, but then gives me the error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` I'll continue to ivestigate this error. I think you've set me in a good direction. Thanks.